# Is the number of atoms per unit cell for Hexagonal Close-packed (HCP) really 6?

Tags: molecular-structure, crystal-structure, materials

I am questioning whether the conventional N=6 for HCP is accurate. This question is spawned from an image in ZYbooks Material Science and Engineering textbook by Callister and Rethwisch, where they show an animation of a HCP. When oriented the unit cell along a plane of a vertical face, the interior atoms clearly bulge out beyond the walls of the unit cell.

[image]

This seems to imply the interior atoms are less than 3, thus N would be less than 6.

Can you demonstrate that the 3 interior atoms are completely within the Unit Cell?

Comment: Are we talking a conventional cell, or unit cell? Either way, an atom is a point, without extent, when assigned to be inside or outside a given cell volume.

Comment: A unit cell. In Materials Science and Engineering, by Callister and Rethwisch, they state without proving that HCP has 6 atoms. I am comfortably able to see that FCC has 4 atoms and BCC has 2 atoms. For HCP it seems like they are assuming the interior atoms are within the bounds of the unit cell. As far as I can tell the interior atoms extend beyond the walls of the Unit Cell.

Comment: It just occurred to me that the bits of the interior atoms that extend beyond the walls, are canceled by adjacent unit cells that extend beyond their own walls in the same way. I'm not 100% sure this is the solution, but it seems to make sense intuitively.

Comment: So, conventional unit cells. Which really aren’t that useful for understanding symmetries. Such as seeing that hcp and fcc are closely related.

Comment: Thanks Jon Custer, that is good to know that the conventional unit cells are not very useful for understanding symmetries. I ended up answering my own question... I'm gonna fix my question back to the original state and provide my answer as a solution. Right now they are kind of jumbled together...

Answer (score 0):

The solution I came up with is yes, the interior atoms do extend beyond the walls of the Unit Cell. However, adjacent Unit Cells also have interior atoms that extend beyond their walls. These bits of volume of the interior atoms, the parts that extend beyond their unit cell, sum to 3 whole interior atoms per unit cell.

Initially I only found it obvious that this would happen for the corner and face atoms (extending into their neighbor cells), but upon closer inspection it is clear the same happens for the interior atoms.

Here is a Desmos file that illustrates this happening with two adjacent Unit cells.

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/zbpiaqxghi